# Can't get basic remote API value shown in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, rest

This is my code, where I am trying to show the values from the remote API which I am trying to fetch via a .php file in Wordpress.

```
<?php 

try {
    $response = wp_remote_get( 'MYURLHERE', array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
        )
    ) );
    if ( ( !is_wp_error($response)) && (200 === wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response ) ) ) {
 $result =  json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response, true) );
 echo $result['data']['0']['id'];

    }
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
    //Handle Exception.
}

?>
```

Getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

What am I doing wrong?

This should be the array:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 124
                    [name] => MyName
                    [supertype] => Mso
```

Comment: "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"- then why not access the data as you would on any stdClass, or convrt it to an array?

Comment: Step 1 when debugging - inspect what you have!  Use [`var_dump()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and friends to look at what data you are getting and what type it is.  You'll probably see `$result` is not an array, explaining your error, then you'll go check [the docs for `json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode) to work out why, and soon you'll understand and solve your problem!

Comment: But it supposed to convert it to an array? That's what I aim with the decode function. Am doing something wrong there?

Comment: You don't use the second parameter in `json_decode()`, `, true` is inside `wp_remote_retrieve_body()`

Comment: I fixed that, but even than I can not show anything. I get 'array' as result. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP manual, you can see the parameters of JSON Function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

This json_decode line of code is wrong, here's the fix:

```
$result =  json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response), true );
```

Comment: There is no error, but I can't see any data if I do that. Is this part okay?  echo $result['data']['0']['id'];

Comment: the function is json_decode(string $json, bool $assoc = ?). if $assoc is true, will return array

Answer (score 0):

You must be outputting a different variable than the one you are getting a error for.

This is because you use json_decode() without any parameters.
This means it will be outputted as an object, not an array.

So the example output you show must originate from some other place than the `$result` you are trying to echo.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? What should I use, in that case?